# "Mailto:" doesn't send email

Tags: javascript, mailto

I wrote this simple code:

```
var email;
do {
     email = prompt('Inserisci il tuo indirizzo eMail');
     if ((email.indexOf("@") == (-1)) || (email == "") || (email == undefined)) {
            alert("Inserisci un indirizzo mail valido");
        }
    }
while ((email.indexOf("@") == (-1)) || (email == "") || (email == undefined));

var subject = ('My Armchair');

var body = new Array();
body[0] = sessionStorage.getItem('imuno');
body[1] = sessionStorage.getItem('imdue');
location.href = "mailto:babini.francesco@queensrl.net" + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body[0] + body[1];
location.href = "../index.html";
```

The check is ok, but it doesn't send the email, someone knows why? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first you cannot send emails in (browser) javascript. You are going to need server-side code to do so.

At most, doing `location.href = "mailto:[…]";` will open the visitor's default mail application with part of it pre filled, but the visitor will still need to click on the send button. And the sender of the email will be the visitor, not you/your website.

If that's what your looking for (the website visitor is actually **manually** sending the email, **not you**), you could open a popup for the `mailto:` link instead of using `window.href`: `window.open("mailto:[…]")`

Otherwise, you'll need a server-side language (PHP, Node.js, etc.) with the code to send the email and add ajax request telling your server to do so in your current JS script.

You should look for PHPMailer (PHP) : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
or
Nodemailer (Node.js) : https://nodemailer.com/

Comment: Yes, i know, thank you for replying! Please read my other comments!

Comment: Please read my answer in its whole, I give you the trick to both open the email page and redirect the visitor :)

Comment: Ops sorry, i missed that part! :)

Answer (score 2):

The browser won't navigate to the new URL until the function has finished running, by the time that happens you have overwritten the `mailto:` URL with an HTTP URL.

Remove the last line.

Comment: I was about to ask if that was the symptom he was seeing... :)

Comment: Actually, that was the problem! How can i move to that URL once the email has been sent then?

Comment: You can't. What if the user is a GMail user? They'll have gone to another website. If you want to have any control over email sending, so it server side from your own systems.

Comment: Since I'm learning lenguages by my own, i haven't started server side lenguages yet.

Comment: In order to move to that URL, I can write another function that just move to other page, can't I?

Comment: No you can't. A `mailto` will mostly open a software (thunderbird, outlook, etc.). So the visitor is not on a webpage anymore, you don't have any control over where he will be. Best case scenario your visitor's mail client is gmail and your best friend is actually working at Google in the gmail department ;)